# Power series radius of convergence and if they are divergent or not

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} e^{-\sqrt n}z^n $

I tried to find the radius of convergence of a power series.. is this equation a geometric series?

or would it be easier to do a ratio test and

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=L$  Then radius of convergence $R=1/L$?

I'm got it converges to $0$, not confident about it though.

Comment: Cauchy-Hadamard Radius Formula.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But you *can* use that ratio test:\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{-\sqrt{n+1}}}{e^{-\sqrt n}}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}e^{\sqrt n-\sqrt{n+1}}\\&=e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt n-\sqrt{n+1}}\\&=e^0\\&=1.\end{align}Therefore, the radius of convergence is $1$.

Comment: How do you do line 2 and 3? I'm quite lost on that :(

Comment: Do you mean the second and the third $=$ signs?

Comment: where you took e out of the limit and made it 0.. I'm curious of the steps

Comment: @MathsGoogle Since the exponential map is continuous, whenever you have a convergen sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$, you have$$\lim_{n\to\infty} e^{a_n}=e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n}.$$And\begin{align}\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt n-\sqrt{n+1}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(\sqrt n-\sqrt{n+1}\right)\left(\sqrt n+\sqrt{n+1}\right)}{\sqrt n+\sqrt{n+1}}\\&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{-1}{\sqrt n+\sqrt{n+1}}\\&=0.\end{align}